# How can I get a certain segment with regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a simple string

`testteststete(segment1)tete(segment2)sttes323testte(segment3)eteste`

I need to get (segment2). Each segment may be any text. I tried to use this regex 
`\(.+\)`. But i get this result

[image]

How i can get (segment2)?
PS: I want to get all of the segments in brackets

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Do you want to get a specific substring like `(segment2)` from your original string?

Comment: @RahulTripathi I want to get all of the segments in brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can just match all the `(...)` substrings and then access the second one using Index 1:

```
var rx = @"\([^)]*\)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, rx).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
var result = matches != null && matches.Count > 1 ? matches[1] : string.Empty;
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Kvjep6)

The regex matches

- `\(` - an opening `(`
- `[^)]*` - 0 or more characters other than `)`
- `\)` - a closing `)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it but this should probably work:

```
\([^\)]*\)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this regex:

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C((%5B%5E)%5D%2B)%5C)&i=testteststete(segment1)tete(segment2)sttes323testte(segment3)eteste)**

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=^[^()]*\([^)]*\)[^()]*\()[^)]*
```

You can simply use this.[See Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B%5E()%5D*%5C(%5B%5E)%5D*%5C)%5B%5E()%5D*%5C()%5B%5E)%5D*&i=testteststete(segment1)tete(segment2)sttes323testte(segment3)eteste)

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\(([^)]*)\)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string secondMatch = regex.Matches(text).Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value.Trim('(', ')'))
    .ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```